# Geoserver OpenLayers CORS error

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, tomcat

I'm trying to publish Mapbox vector tiles from my GeoServer using OpenLayers. I'm a total novice when it comes to everything around web mapping, web design etc. I'm using GeoServer deployed locally on my Windows 10 machine through Tomcat. I´ve gone through [this](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html) official tutorial, but pointing to my own data, code looking this this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vector tiles</title>
  <script src="ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css">
  <style>
    html, body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .map {
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Mapbox Protobuf - vector tiles</h3>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>

  var style_simple = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#ADD8E6'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#880000',
      width: 1
    })
  });

  function simpleStyle(feature) {
    return style_simple;
  }

  var layer = 'SKS:sksbiotopskydd';
  var projection_epsg_no = '3006';
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    }),
    layers: [new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      style:simpleStyle,
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        tilePixelRatio: 1, // oversampling when > 1
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        url: '/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer +
            '@EPSG%3A'+projection_epsg_no+'@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
      })
    })]
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

When I try to open the map, the data does not display, and inspecting the page shows the error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/SKS:sksbiotopskydd@EPSG%3A3006@pbf/2/0/2.pbf. (Reason: CORS request not http).

I´ve tried to read up on CORS, but not sure I totally grasp the concept. I've also tried activating CORS in Tomcat (by uncommenting the filters in the web.xml), but that doesn´t help (gives the same error message). What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message there is a clue "Reason: CORS request not http" - you are accessing a file not a web page so the Same Origin Policy disallows the request.

Make sure your web request starts with `http://localhost` (or other host).

Comment: I tried that (think I did that before too while bashing my head on this), now I instead get the error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/SKS:sksbiotopskydd@EPSG%3A3006@pbf/2/3/1.pbf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).` I just realised too, I only activated CORS in the Geoserver XML, do I need to do it in Tomcat in some way too? Do I even need CORS activated to accomplish this?

Comment: are you setting the CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'? because Tomcat thinks it is missing.

Comment: Is this something I'm supposed to do in the Tomcat web.xml or in the Geoserver web.xml? I´ve uncommented both cors-related filters I could find mentioned in the Geoserver web.xml. Sorry if these are trivial questions, but I found it´s kind of hard to get over the first threshold on this without much previous knowledge on the topic...

Comment: NVM, I got rid id of the CORS error now by modifying the web.xml. However, now I get a `400: Bad request` error instead, which I guess would have to do with the url to my data? I'm starting to feel I just won´t be able to solve this myself...